# How to pause MPMoviePlayerController when going to another tab?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

What is the right way for pausing MPMoviePlayerController when tapping another tab bar item and going to another view? I need MPMoviePlayerController somehow to be shared between tab bar view controllers in order to pause video. Is there another way to pause a video, some event like "whenViewIsOffScreen" or smith?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably can use either viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear to pause the video and viewWillAppear or viewdidAppear to resume playing it. Implement these methods in the view controller that contains your video.

Something like this :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.moviePlayer pause];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have root view controller you can do it like **sch** wrote or
if you do have rootVC, you can put mentioned methods in rootVC's *switchView* method, so you won't have - if not expected - stop/play music in other situations like going to background, but only when switching views